# Converting solutions to separation constant to Cosh and Sinh

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations

The Laplace's equation inside a rectangle is:

$$u_{\text{xx}}+u_{\text{yy}}\text{=0}$$

The IC's are:

$${u(0,y)=g(y)}$$
$${u(L,y)=0}$$
$${u(x,0)=0}$$
$${u(x,H)=0}$$

Via method of separation we have

$$1) \  X"(x)-X(x)\lambda=0$$
$$2) \  Y"(y)+Y(y)\lambda=0$$

Because Y is a boundary value problem, 
we have the eigenfunction: $$Y_n(y)=\sin(\beta _n y)$$
The eigenvalue is: $$\lambda _n=(\beta_n)^2= \left(\frac{n \pi \ }{H} \right)^2$$

Substitute $\lambda_n$ into (1) and we have $$X''(x) - \left( \frac{n\pi }{H}\right)^2 X(x) = 0$$
Continuing on, we check for cases for which $\lambda$ does not produce a trivial solution. This is when $$\lambda >0$$. The problem I run into is converting the solution into Cosh and Sinh.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The general solution to $X'' - \omega^2 X=0$ is  $X(x) = A \cosh (\omega x) + B \sinh(\omega x).$   You have $\omega = \frac{n\pi}{H}.$

Comment: My solution to X(x) is
$$X(x)=\text{X(x)=}\text{ce}^{\left(\frac{n\pi
   }{H}\right)x}+\text{de}^{\left(\frac{-n\pi }{H}\right)x}$$
How does that lead to Cosh and Sin form? I'm not familiar with Cosh and Sinh.

Comment: OK.  You have two solutions $X_1(x)= e^{\omega x}$ and $X_2(x)=e^{-\omega x},$ where $\omega = n\pi/H.$     You add/subtract  these solutions to get new solutions: $X_3(x) = \frac{1}{2} (X_1(x) + X_2(x) ) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{\omega_x} + e^{-\omega x}) $  and $X_4(x)=\frac{1}{2} (X_1(x) - X_2(x) ) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{\omega x} - e^{-\omega x}).$   Now recall that $\cosh (z) = \frac{1}{2} (e^z + e^{-z})$ and $\sinh z = \frac{1}{2} (e^z - e^{-z}).$

Comment: I'm curious as to the intent and purpose in which you "spilt" X(x) into X1 and X2 and then divide them by 2

Comment: The $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ functions are defined in terms of sums of exponentials and vice versa.   That is, BY Defintion:  $\cosh(z)=0.5(e^z + e^{-z})$ and $\sinh(z) = 0.5(e^z - e^{-z})$ and therefore $e^z=\cosh z + \sinh z,$ $e^{-z} = \cosh z- \sinh z.$

Comment: The purpose of "splitting" was to generate $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ from the exponentials.

Comment: Is there an alternative solution to not use Cosh and Sinh?